# Identical field names causing error in system

Tags: java, postgresql, ejb, wildfly

The question itself will be updated along until the error is clear.

We recently did an upgrade on our system a few months back from JBoss to Wildfly and our system has gone buggy ever since.

Lets say I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE students(
    ID int,
    Classid int,
    Name varchar(50),
    Version int
)

CREATE TABLE classstudent(
    ID int,
    Classname varchar(50),
    Version int
)
```

---

I write the following query and it worked

```
select *
from students
```

---

I write the following but it doesnt work

```
select *
from students s
join classStudent cs on cs.id = s.classid
```

---

So I decided to select each field

```
select s.id,s.classid,c.name,s.version,cs.id,cs.classname,cs.version
from students s
join classStudent cs on cs.id = s.classid
```

---

I still get an error so I decided to select the 2 ids from each table

```
select s.id,cs.id
from students s
join classStudent cs on cs.id = s.classid
```

---

I got an error one more time but then I renamed the ids to different names

```
select s.id as sid,cs.id as csid
from students s
join classStudent cs on cs.id = s.classid
```

This query worked, so clearly whenever there are identical field names on either table, the system throws an error.

What is this problem and how can I solve this problem? Where should I start looking? Any link to help point me in the right direction would be greatful!

```
error
----

WFLYEJB0443: EJB 3.1 FR 13.3.3: BMT bean SqlSearchExecutionSessionBean should complete transaction before returning.
```

As I said however before, this is a general error and I sometimes get it too when I misspell a table name or field name!

Comment: 1. What is this error? What do you do with these queries? If you use the same name in a further query this would fail 2. is there a problem with your table names? In Postgres every name is with non capital letters at default.

Comment: That is a really good example on why `select *` should be avoided in production code.

Comment: your right @S-Man that was a mispelling from my part regardinf table names. The error is a general error which usually has nothing to do with the error. but for your reference its WFLYEJB0443: EJB 3.1 FR 13.3.3: BMT bean SqlSearchExecutionSessionBean should complete transaction before returning.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the database is soo massive and complex, there is no erd map for it. So whenever I am retrieving data from a table I dont know of, I usually do a select * and join maybe a few tables to see corresponding values! Without select all my work would have been drastically slowed down!

Comment: It's like you got 2 kid in a house and both of them have same name Tito, Now on calling `Tito` who should reply back? Or if you are calling someone who doesn't exist in house who will reply back? Same way coding languages don't understand these case and throw error when you try to multiple same name in same house or calling someone who doesn't exist.

Comment: @NAVIN If I do a select * in a house! Then I expect all the kids to better come down when I say ALL!
Nice example with the house though! ;-)

Comment: in sql you might say * but internally mapping is done, we can't have 2 column with same name in sql, can we? thus this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query result can't have identical column names as a result.
So the column name `id` can only exist once in your SELECT statement.

Therefore I would try this:

```
select s.id, s.classid, c.name, s.version, cs.classname, cs.version
from Students s
join ClassStudent cs on cs.id = s.classid
```

In here you don't have to mention `cs.id` since it is always equal to `s.id` as it is in your join statement. However, if you do want it in your query you could give it an alias like this `cs.id AS csid` (or some other unused name) and add this to your SELECT statement.

Comment: Same named columns are not problem for a query. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e71a7ce8104fea0cdf43e89b6b605fd7 It would be a problem if you try to reference them.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend if you are having an error with the same field in different tables, try to just put them this way instead of give the table an alias:

```
select Students.id,ClassStudent.id
from Students
join ClassStudent on ClassStudent.id = Student.classid
```